# Redirect on AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js

I generally have the following common code to make AJAX requests in my app;

```
doXhr: function(postData, requestUrl){  
    var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {        
        return $.ajax({
            url: requestUrl,

        })
        .done(function(response, status, xhrObject) {         
          resolve(response);
        })
        .fail(function(xhrObject, status, error){           
            reject(errorObj);
        });
    })  
    return promise;
},
```

I invoke this as below

```
postToExternal: function(args, url) {
        var deferred =  this.doXhr(args,url);
        return deferred;        
    }
```

For one of the requirements, I need to make a POST AJAX request & the server wold then redirect (302) to some other URL

So my question is would the above way of calling doXhr() still work i.e. returning deferred

OR since I know it is going to be a redirect, I should just use $.ajax() and leave (as there is no use of waiting for the promise to be resolved)

Comment: So you do not care about the response? Than do not worry about the response and continue on.

Comment: Actually in this case it is going to be a redirect from the server...So just wondering if returning a promise is of any use

Comment: The browser is not going to redirect....

Comment: If server does a redirect in reply to an ajax call, the browser will not be redirected.

Comment: Then how can I make the UI change to the URL (I want it after making a POST call to the server)

Comment: I am getting this error when I tried the redirect with a local server...XMLHttpRequest cannot load Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Comment: To make a redirect we handle the returning http status code, if a 302 status code recieved, we manually redirect the url.

Comment: Are you getting a cors error?

Comment: Yes, XMLHttpRequest cannot load Response for preflight is invalid (redirect) ....Can you give an example of how you are handling redirect...I need to make a POST request (sending some data to the server) which would then redirect..

Comment: It depends on what you are using to transition, controller, route etc - but generally, you should be able to use a promise and a .then to ensure it's complete and then use one of the various transition methods: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute  ~ But I may be missing the nuances of the situation. Maybe creating tasks with ember-concurency would be good for this?